# Is there a way to prevent VSCode from automatically trying to activate conda in certain terminals (e.g., R terminal)

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

It is convenient to automatically start the Conda environment in a Python terminal. But I would like this feature to be turned off when using an R terminal, for example, the [radian](https://github.com/randy3k/radian) (in which case `conda activate base` will only lead to an error message, quite annoying).

Is there a way to prevent VSCode from automatically starting the Conda environment when using certain terminals?

Answer (score 1):

I have just got an answer for myself. The setting I required in my post might be unnecessary, as you can start `radian` manually in a non-R terminal and set `r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal` to `True`.